# How to thread, pipe or compose functions in lua?

Tags: lua, functional-programming, code-structure

What to do in lua if I want to pass a value to foo(), pass it's return to bar(), pass it's return to baz() etc?

Exhibit A (pseudocode):

```
backwards(code(reading(like(not(do(I))))))
```

Exhibit B (pseudocode):

```
local all = foo(...)
local this = bar(all)
local variables = baz(this)
local obscure_a_simple_idea = quux(variables)
```

In F# this code ([source](https://fsharpforyou.github.io/chapters/learning_the_language/function_composition/piping.html))

```
let numbers = [0..100]
let evenNumbers = List.filter isEven numbers
let doubledNumbers = List.map double evenNumbers
List.iter printNumber doubledNumbers
```

can be rewritten like this:

```
[0..100]
|> List.filter isEven
|> List.map double
|> List.iter printNumber
```

In clojure this code ([source](https://clojure.org/guides/threading_macros))

```
(defn calculate []
   (reduce + (map #(* % %) (filter odd? (range 10)))))
```

Can be written like this

```
(defn calculate* []
   (->> (range 10)
        (filter odd? ,,,)
        (map #(* % %) ,,,)
        (reduce + ,,,)))
```

I am aware that [fennel has threading macros](https://fennel-lang.org/reference#------and---threading-macros). What I would like to know: what can I do in lua? Did I miss a language feature? Is there some well-known ideom I am not aware of? Am I stuck choosing between exhibit A, exhibit B, or migrating to fennel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good news: Lua has first-class functions so pretty much all of this is possible in plain Lua! (It may be more verbose and/or inefficient, though.)

Let's start with function composition:

```lua
function compose(f, g)
    return function(...)
        return g(f(...))
    end
end
```

I've flipped `f` and `g` here, so `f(g(x))` would be equivalent to `compose(g, f)(x)`.

Let's write a left fold on a vararg:

```lua
function foldl(f, acc, ...)
    if select("#", ...) == 0 then
        return acc
    end
    local l = ...
    return foldl(f, f(acc, l), select(2, ...))
end
```

Let's also define the identity function:

```lua
function id(...) return ... end
```

Now let's take care of Exhibit A:

```lua
function chain(...) return foldl(compose, id, ...) end
chain(dont, like, reading, code, backwards)(I)
```

Since chaining is just composition with another order, it returns a function, so the argument is still on the right. If you're not happy with this, you could write yourself a function which takes the argument and does the call, similar to the threading F# / Clojure have to offer:

```lua
function chaincall(arg, ...) return chain(...)(arg) end
```

Now your Exhibit A becomes `chaincall(I, dont, like, reading, code, backwards)`.

Exhibit B is pretty much the same: You can do `chain(foo, bar, baz, quux)(...)`. `chaincall` won't work with a vararg as first parameter, though: The vararg would be truncated to its first value.

Voilà! Essentially we've implemented Clojure's `->>` now: `chaincall(x, ...)` is equivalent to `(->> x ...)`.

F#'s `|>` is somewhat harder to do, because it requires us to somehow deal with a list of arguments to follow the "threaded" argument per function. One way to do it would be using a "right curry" which appends arguments to a function call:

```lua
function curry_right(f, ...)
    local args, n_curried = {...}, select("#", ...)
    return function(...)
        local n = select("#", ...)
        local concat = {...}
        for i = 1, n_curried do
            concat[n + i] = args[i]
        end
        return f(table.unpack(concat, 1, n + n_curried))
    end
end
```

Then you could just do:

```lua
chaincall(range(0, 100),
    curry_right(List.filter, isEven, numbers),
    curry_right(List.map, double, evenNumbers),
    curry_right(List.iter, printNumber, doubledNumbers))
```

similar to F# (assuming suitable definitions of `range` etc.)

---

As is often the case in Lua, it gives you the power to implement this yourself, pushing tradeoffs and design decisions on you.

Even with the simple implementations I have provided, there are  discussions to be had:

- How to namespace these functions. For simplicity, I'm just "polluting" the global namespace here.
- How to implement these functions. You could consider directly implementing a `compose_multiple` using a table of functions, for example. You could consider using the identity function and making a fold which requires a vararg with at least one element.
- How / whether to optimize these functions. I brushed performance concerns aside here.

A related library worth mentioning is [`luafun`](https://github.com/luafun/luafun), which provides functions like `filter` and `map`. That library also showcases another frequently chosen way of (emulating) this "chaining": By means of "methods" on "objects" (tables with metatables) which in turn return the objects. For example you could have an "iterator" object. Calling `iterator:filter(f)` would return a new iterator, on which you could then call `map`: `iterator:filter(f):map(g)` etc.

---

Using Lua's metatables, you could even get some syntactic sugar. Let's repurpose the right shift operator (`f >> g`) for "flipped" function composition:

```lua
debug.setmetatable(function()end, {__shr = function(g, f) return function(...) return f(g(...)) end end})
function square(x) return x^2 end
(square >> print)(4) -- 16.0
```

(In older Lua versions, you'd have to use a different operator. Also note that this probably isn't the best idea in "serious" code due to performance and readability concerns; such "abuse" of the debug library is usually frowned upon in "serious" code, and many "safe" environments may remove or restrict the `debug` library altogether. Static analysis tools might also get confused.)